# How to set custom log in apache httpd.conf file?

Tags: java, apache

I have a trouble in setting CustomLog directive in apache httpd.conf file.
I want to view log messages with java program.
So I have set the CustomLog directive as following.

```
CustomLog "| \"c:/Program Files(x86)/java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java.exe\" -jar bin/bedei-apache.jar" combined
```

By the way while beginning apache I get a error.

```
AH00104: unable to start piped log program ' "c:/Program Files(x86)/java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java.exe" -jar bin/bedei-apache.jar': The system cannot find the path specified.  
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

I have tried several ways to tell the apache the correct path of java.exe.
But only in one case I have successed.

```
CustomLog "| 'c:/Progra~2/java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java.exe' -jar bin/bedei-apache.jar" combined
```

But I want to set the full path of java.exe not like "c:/Progra~2/..."
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Just stick to the syntax given in the documentation. Don't make up your own.

Answer (score 0):

Quote the entire thing and escape spaces.

CustomLog "|c:/Program\ Files/java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java.exe -jar bin/bedei-apache.jar" combined

Comment: Thank you for your answer.By the way the same error occurs still.`AH00104: unable to start piped log program ' c:/Program\\ Files(x86)/java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java.exe -jar bin/bedei-apache.jar': The system cannot find the path specified.  
AH00015: Unable to open logs`

Comment: I want help of yours. Are there any people to help me? Please reply me.